# Symfony Own Private Vendor

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php, vendor

I have a private bundle that I import in the vendor.

Now, I'm working in my project and want to edit some code in the vendor bundle.

Now I've done that and want to commit to code, so I go the dir of that bundle and say: "`git commit -a`" so I give a message, save and now I have a commit. Oke, "`git push`" and give the response "Everything is up-to-date"... So I can't push that but I can commit??

Is this not a way to commit? Should I just clone the repo and work there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a long time ago that I asked this question. Mean while I got the answer but never updated my stackoverflow question, sorry for that!

The answer on my own question is to get the dependency with composer `--prefer-source`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

> --prefer-source: There are two ways of downloading a package: `source` and `dist`. For stable versions composer will use the `dist` by default. The `source` is a version control repository. If `--prefer-source` is enabled, composer will install from `source` if there is one. This is useful if you want to make a bugfix to a project and get a local git clone of the dependency directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should never edit the vendor code directly - this is the whole point of dependency management.

Composer basically works by looking at your `composer.json` file, and fetching the repositories and versions you specify. If you need to make changes to one of your dependencies, you should make the change in the original repository, push the changes up to GitHub (or wherever you're hosting the code) and run `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

When Composer installs a vendor, it checks out a particular commit, so you are not on a branch. You need to checkout the `master` branch — or whichever you're using — and commit to it and push it.